# How to match column attribute in a data table to a column value in a lookup table with R

Tags: r, match, apply, attr

This should be something easy but I cannot figure it out.

I have a data table with N columns and a lookup table that has two columns: New.Name and Number. I would like to rename the columns in the data table with the New.Name found in the lookup table matching by Number. Not all column names will have a New.Name in the lookup table. Number in the data table is stored as a column attribute. So I need to match the column attribute in the data table to the value found in the Number column in the lookup table.

Example:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20), ncol = 5))
colnames(df) <- c('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno')
for (i in 1:5) attr(df[,i], 'Number') <- i

lookup <- data.frame(Number=c(2,3),New.Name=c('x','y'))
```

What's the best way to rename column def and column ghi to x and y per example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by

```
names(df)[match(lookup$Number, unlist(lapply(df, attributes)) )] <- as.character(lookup$New.Name)
names(df)
#[1] "abc" "x"   "y"   "jkl" "mno"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy... Maybe this will work:

```
colnames(df)[sapply(lookup$Number, function(x) which(sapply(df,attr, 'Number')==x))] <- as.character(lookup$New.Name)
```

Comment: It's usually better to edit and undelete an existing answer, instead of entering a new one.